# Power BI Custom Visuals Conditional Formatting

Tags: d3.js, powerbi, conditional-formatting, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have made a PowerBi custom visual using D3.js. I want to add conditional formatting specifically for gradient. I have figured out how to get one. But in the conditional formatting window I am not able to work with "min value", "middle value" & "max value". My chart gets data dynamically so the min, max, middle value changes. How can I fix this issue?

Here is my settings.ts file,

```
import { formattingSettings } from "powerbi-visuals-utils-formattingmodel";

import FormattingSettingsCard = formattingSettings.Card;
import FormattingSettingsSlice = formattingSettings.Slice;
import FormattingSettingsModel = formattingSettings.Model;

export class ColorSettings extends FormattingSettingsCard{
    public defaultColor = new formattingSettings.ColorPicker({
        name: "defaultColor",
        displayName: "Default Color",
        value: { value: "#EFF3FF" },
        // selector: dataViewWildcard.createDataViewWildcardSelector(dataViewWildcard.DataViewWildcardMatchingOption.InstancesAndTotals),
        // altConstantValueSelector: barDataPoint.selectionId.getSelector(),
        instanceKind: powerbi.VisualEnumerationInstanceKinds.ConstantOrRule,
    });

    public name: string = "color";
    public displayName: string = "Color";
    public slices: FormattingSettingsSlice[] = [this.defaultColor]
}

export class VisualSettings extends FormattingSettingsModel {
    public color: ColorSettings = new ColorSettings();
    public cards: FormattingSettingsCard[] = [this.color];
}
```

And here is the block where I am getting the value from the code,

```
 this.visualSettings = this.formattingSettingsService.populateFormattingSettingsModel(VisualSettings, options.dataViews);
 this.defaultColor = this.visualSettings.color.defaultColor.value.value;
```

and here's where I am using it,

```
selectPath
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .merge(selectPath)
            .attr('class', 'pathEle')
            .attr("fill", this.defaultColor) //here
```

Need some assistance to get a gradient for min, mis and max value.

**NOTE:** I know I can use d3 scaleLinear and make that happen by giving an option to manually select colors for min, mid and max values. But I want to use **conditional formatting**.